# Error Check Internet Connection use flutter

Tags: flutter

There is an error in the following code

> The argument type 'dynamic Function(ConnectivityResult)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(List)?'.

```
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class InternetController extends GetxController {
  Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen(Netstatus);
  }

  Netstatus(ConnectivityResult cr) {
    if (cr == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      Get.rawSnackbar(
        title: 'No Internet',
        message: 'Connect to internet to proceed',
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.wifi_off,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        isDismissible: true,
        duration: Duration(days: 1),
        shouldIconPulse: true,
      );
    } else {
      if (Get.isSnackbarOpen) {
        Get.closeCurrentSnackbar();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

check internet connection flutter

Comment: The error is clear, you are assigning a function which takes only an input of type `ConnectivityResult` to a function which expects as input a `List`

Answer (score 0):

The listener callback returns a list not a connectivity result object, your code should look something like this (as per docs):

```
StreamSubscription<List<ConnectivityResult>> subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((List<ConnectivityResult> result) {
    // Received changes in available connectivity types!
});
```

Within the callback check the first item in the list (seems weird but its how its done in the example of the library).

see https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus/example

make sure to unsubscribe from the subscription in your dispose method